# Does Nautilus exclude any items from its search results?

Tags: nautilus, configuration, search

When I searched for a file called `60-evdev.hwdb` using Nautilus for instance, although it took about half an hour, in the end it returned to say that it couldn't find such a file on my machine.

However when I ran a search with `locate` in Terminal it found it almost immediately and it was here:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4891 May 12 10:39 /lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-evdev.hwdb
```

So why couldn't Nautilus find it? Does Nautilus filter out certain types of items or something? If so, is there any way to tweak or disable this filter? I should also be noted that if I go into the folder where I now know the file is with Nautilus it can see it there, just not find it through searching, but as it uses a real-time search it should really find it, shouldn't it?

I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Comment: Where were you searching from? I'd be stunned if Nautilus searched the whole of `/` for anything the user asked.

Comment: @muru: I used the standard search facility when I went into the `/` directory. It took ages, but didn't find anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nautilus search ...

1. if [tracker](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Tracker) is available it will show the results from that.

   From the link:

   > Tracker provides the following:
   >
   > - Indexer for desktop search (for more details see this spec : https://wiki.ubuntu.com/IntegratedDesktopSearch)
   > - Tag database for doing keyword tagging of any object
   > - Extensible metadata database for apps like gedit and rhythmbox which need to add custom metadata to files
   > - Database for first class objects allows using tracker's database for storage and implementation of First Class Objects and the Gnome 3.0 Model.
2. if there is no tracker it uses `find`.

Check if `trackerd` is active. That would have Nautilus use option 1. The time you indicate would have me believe it used the 2nd option.

Possibility: you have `trackerd` active but it is not accurate. Though that does not explain why it took a 1/2 hour.

---

Nautilus found the file in less than a second for me (it instantly came back):

[image]

So I assume yours was using "find". You probably need to redo the search and check the process list for what it does when searching.

---

Using find also got it back within a second:

```
$ find / -name 60-evdev.hwdb -print |more 
find: ‘/var/lib/mysql-files’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/mysql’: Permission denied
/lib/udev/hwdb.d/60-evdev.hwdb
find: ‘/var/lib/udisks2’: Permission denied
find: ‘/var/lib/colord/.cache’: Permission denied
...
```

---

The link also provides a method on disabling tracker but your problem is probably that the tracker is not running.

> Disabling tracker for globally (for all users)
>
> Edit `/etc/xdg/autostart/trackerd.desktop` file with root priviledges (sudo vim, gksudo gedit ...). Add `Hidden=true` to the end of the file. Do the same for `/etc/xdg/autostart/tracker-applet.desktop` if you want

---

> Disabling tracker for your user only. Enter the directory 
>   `~/.config/autostart`, create it if it does not exist. Create a file
>   named `trackerd.desktop`. Paste the following into the file, save and
>   exit
>
> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Encoding=UTF-8
> Name=Tracker
> Hidden=true
> ```

Comment: `trackerd.desktop` does not seem to be in any of the autostart locations, should it be by default? So how exactly do I enable it? What should the `.desktop` file look like?

Comment: I tested on both Nautilus and Nemo without tracker running - no `find` processes were running. Though Nautilus was much faster than Nemo in finding it

Comment: @ParanoidPanda but you want to find it don't you? then don't use the last bit :+) Make sure trackerd is running.